# No viable conversion from 'darray<Foo>' to 'Foo'

Tags: c++, templates

We are required to basically write our own vector class for a homework assignment, which I've done (but I cannot completely post for obvious reasons).

```
darray<Foo> * foos = new darray<Foo>();

...

Foo foo = foos[i]; // No viable conversion from 'darray<Foo>' to 'Foo'

...

// In darray

template<typename T>
T & darray<T>::operator[] (unsigned index)
{
    return store[index];
}
```

I don't understand what's going on. Why isn't the bracket operator working? It's suppose to return an instance of type Foo, yet the compiler seems to be oblivious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `darray` is, but I'm assuming it's analagous to `std::array`.

`foos` is a pointer, as such it can be treated as a regular C-style array, which is what your code is currently doing, and why it's failing.

Two possible solutions. The first is to change this line:

```
darray<Foo> * foos = new darray<Foo>();
```

to this line:

```
darray<Foo> foos;
```

The other solution is to dereference the pointer you've made, like so:

```
Foo& foo = (*foos)[i];
```